# How to get from momentum to force

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation

Situation:

I have a solid object (black) attached to a rod (blue) as shown below:

[image]

The rod is fixed at the top. The solid object is a cylinder as shown, with a rate of rotation  $\omega~\text{rad/s}$. I have the mass (and hence moment of inertia) of the solid object and I would like to calculate the induced stress on the rod.

So far I've calculated the kinetic energy of the cylinder $$\mathbf{KE} = \dfrac{\mathbf{I} \cdot {\omega}^2}{2}$$.

It seems if I had a torque acting on the rod I would be able to calculate the induced stress a lot more readily, however I'm not sure how to get from my current values to the torque. I've tried to work though a similar linear problem (as I seem to find rotational mechanics harder), but if I had a cantilever beam with a mass at one end with a given velocity I still wouldn't know what to do.

Comment: You are looking for a single value?  If the object does not slip on the rod, then the stress cannot be constant.  As the object rotates, the stress and torque increase.  If you have a formula for how the torque increases, you can integrate over it to find when the object will be brought to stop.

Comment: You are quite right. The area I'm getting stuck with is the time side of things. Can you point me to a good example/tutorial of this sort of problem (doesn't need to be angular - I'd probably understand linear better).

Comment: I believe you can use the linear analogy of a bullet shot at a mass that has a spring resisting the motion. You would use the equation that uses the spring constant and the associated masses and set them equal to the KE of the bullet.  In your case you need to use the equation relating the properties of the blue rod (torsion constant,etc.) and set it equal to the KE of the cylinder. Good luck.